# how to save many foreign key at one cell

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i have two tables on mysql

### Item Table

| Id | item_name | room_id | other column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table | 1 |  |
| 2 | book | 2 |  |
| 3 | clock | 2 |  |

### Room Table

| id | room_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Teacher room |
| 2 | class room |

I have a case that one item can be in several rooms,

I was asked for the data not to be duplicated as follows

| Id | item_name | room_id | other column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table | 1 |  |
| 2 | table | 2 |  |

how to store at one row column room_id has many value like this

| Id | item_name | room_id | other column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table | 1,2 |  |

I've done it using a string and then I extracted it using explode() but in mysql table I can't connect to the room table anymore

Comment: Do not use ```item_name``` in the second table, but use just ```id``` for the second table. Because you have already the item_name from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a pivot table

- table: item_room
- columns: item_id, room_id

Models should look like this

```
namespace App\Models;

class Item extends Model
{
    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class)->using(ItemRoom::class);
    }
}

namespace App\Models;

class Room extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->using(ItemRoom::class);
    }
}

namespace App\Models;

class ItemRoom extends Pivot
{
    
}

# you can get data using eager loading, querying relation, etc.
$room = Room::find(1);
foreach($room->items() as $items){
    //todo
}

$item = Item::find(1);
foreach($item->rooms() as $items){
   //todo
}
```

Comment: A pivot class is not necessary. Having a pivot table is necessary.